# Euclid's algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

If we begin to use a Sieve of Eratosthenes on the set of naturals from $1$ through $200$, eliminating all multiples of $2, 3, 5$ and $7$ how many composite numbers will remain?

This is a question from a homework. The answer I got was $0$. I am just looking to see if I'm right.

The way I see it, is that after you run the algorithm, all that is left are prime numbers. I understand that it asks to eliminate only $2, 3, 5, 7$ but all other numbers end up being divisible by $2, 3, 5$ or $7$.

Am I correct to assume this?

Comment: 121 remains.   .   .

Comment: 11(13)= 143 is another,   Multiply prime numbers larger than 7 until you get larger than 200.

Comment: oh yes. I drew a table but I made some mistakes. thanks!